# How do I use coroutines in my Kotlin code to read in phone sensor data one by one?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-sensors, data-collection, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to read sensor data from multiple sensors into a .txt file. I would like for the data to read in nicely so that it would be easy to read. Right now I've gotten the data to write to a .txt file but the data reads in very sloppy and at different rates. It appears that the sensors are listening and writing at different rates. I would like for each sensor to get their data and then wait for the next sensor to get the data and then the next until the final one and then write to the .txt file. From what I understand coroutines can help me do that but I'm trying to figure out how to implement it.

This is where I call on the sensors.

```
           val accelSensor: Sensor? = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            val gyroSensor: Sensor? = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)
            val lightSensor: Sensor? = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)

            if(accelSensor != null && gyroSensor != null && lightSensor != null) {


                sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelSensor, readSpeed)
                sensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroSensor, readSpeed)
                sensorManager.registerListener(this, lightSensor, readSpeed)


            }
```

This is my onSensorChanged listener.

```
 @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onSensorChanged(p0: SensorEvent?) {

        val path = this.getExternalFilesDir(null)
        val folder = File(path, "AppData")
        val file = File(folder, "AppData.txt")

        data = data + "${time.format(formatter)} , "

        if (safetyType == 0) {

            data = data + "Safe, "

        }
        else if (safetyType == 1) {

            data = data + "Unsafe, "

        }

        if (p0 != null) {



            if ( p0.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {


                accelerometerTextView.text =
                    "Accelerometer X: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[0]) +
                        " Y: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[1]) + " Z: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[2])

                data = data +  "Accel X: "+ "%.4f".format(p0.values[0]) +
                        " Y: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[1]) + " Z: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[2]) + " , "

            }

            if (p0.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {

                gyroscopeTextView.text =
                    "Gyroscope X: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[0]) +
                            " Y: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[1]) + " Z: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[2])

                data = data +  "Gyro X: "+ "%.4f".format(p0.values[0]) +
                        " Y: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[1]) + " Z: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[2]) + " , "

            }

            if (p0.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {

                lightTextView.text =
                    "Light Level: " + "%.4f".format(p0.values[0])

                data = data + "%.4f".format(p0.values[0]) + " , \n\n"


                file.appendText(data)
                data = ""

            }



        }



    }
```

[Here is what my current output looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0b4J.png)

[Here is a made-up example of how I would like for the output to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxRL0.png)

I tried to use If statements to check which sensor is being activated to read in the data one by one but it still ended up just reading in the data very sloppy and all over the place.

Comment: What do you mean by sloppy? Can you give an example of what it looks like now and what you would like it to look like? Why do you mention coroutines in your question?

Comment: Sensors read at different rates. Do you want to log them at whatever the slowest rate is, dropping the extra values from the faster sensors?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I would like the sensors to wait for one another and then log the data before moving on and getting new data. I have the sensor rate set to a custom speed every few seconds.

Comment: From your output and code, it looks like `onSensorChanged` will execute if one of the sensor changes. What happens if only one changes? Does it have to wait for the other two to also change before writing to the file? What happens if the others don't change?